# bug or i don't understand "evolve"

Tags: ramda.js

When using `Ramda.remove()` by itself the function takes an array and outputs an array:

```
const grid = {rows: [1, 2, 3]};

R.remove(1, 1, grid.rows) // output: [1,3]
```

When I use `Ramda.remove()` as a transformation function in `Ramda.evolve()` it becomes an object `{"0": 1, "1": 2, "2": 3}` instead of an array `[1,3]`:

```
const grid = {rows: [1, 2, 3]};

R.evolve({
  rows:  R.remove(1, 1, grid.rows)
})(grid); // output:{"rows": {"0": 1, "1": 2, "2": 3}}
```

Do I understand `evolve` correctly or is a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine what you most likely want is

```
rows: R.remove(1, 1)
```

That will give you a function from a list to a shortened version of that list.

Comment: That's it! Thank you, Scott!

Answer (score 0):

Just when writing this issue I realized what's wrong. I had to wrap `R.remove` in a function or bind the args. Basically, I needed to pass the reference to the function.

`rows: () => R.remove(1, 1, grid.rows)`